# Android: Calling method in intervals to retrieve the latest location coordinates

Tags: java, android, location, intervals

Hi! I had a locationlistener and manager in my Mainactivity class but I thought that was quite a bad solution, Since i want the location functionallity in a different class because i want the listener to last over Intents.

I only have around 10 hours experience in Android Programming so this might look horrible for some people ;)

**Main Activity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_xxx);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    location = new RetrieveLocation(this);
    checkForPermission();
    ...


//I want this method to call location.getCoordinates() in 1 second intervals
public void updateMap()  {

        if (location.hasFoundLocation()) {
            enableButton();
            marker.setPosition(location.getCoordinates());
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location.getCoordinates(), 16));

        }
        else {
            disableButton();
        }
}


public void checkForPermission()
{

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        }, 10);
    }
    else {
        location.listen();
        updateMap();
    }
}
```

So retrieveLocation class basically just updates the user position when the device is moved.

**So i want to grab the coordinates to the mainActivity class every second and update the marker on Google Maps**.

**RetrieveLocation**

```
public class RetrieveLocation
{
private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener locationListener;
private LatLng _location;
private Context context;
public RetrieveLocation(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
    locationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
}


public void listen()
{
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            _location = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
    //noinspection ResourceType
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
}

...

public LatLng getCoordinates()
{
    if(_location != null)
        return _location;
    else
        return new LatLng(0,0);
}
```

*I have searched quite a lot before writing this post*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your listener to last over intents, you should call it from a service and subscribe for the events from there.  On the event receive, you also have to update your UI.

Comment: Ah sweet, how could i have missed this? Thanks!